# Mod-Rewrite exclude a specific link from rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very simple mod rewrite script taking my php variables and making them into .html files. It works however, I would like to confirm my google webmaster tools url, and it is not working because the url structure is being rewritten. How can i exclude a specific item?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

URL i would like to exclude from the rewrite process:

```
http://www.website.com/google149e37e6d0ddce9a.html
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^google149e37e6d0ddce9a.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The dash is a special value meaning nothing will be rewritten. The [L] stops evaluation upon a successful match.

Comment: @user1204678 Awesome, but you did not accept the answer. Check **Accept** below the number of votes in the top left of this box.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use something like:

```
RewriteRule ^google[0-9a-f]+.html$ - [L]
```

So that you can upload verification files later and not have this problem.